# How do i select only certain rows based on label in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, slice, finance

Here is my function:

```
def get_historical_closes(ticker, start_date, end_date):
   my_dir = '/home/manish/Desktop/Equity/subset'
   os.chdir(my_dir)

   dfs = []
   for files in glob.glob('*.txt'):
      dfs.append(pd.read_csv(files, names = ['Ticker', 'Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Null'], parse_dates = [1]))

      p = pd.concat(dfs)
      d = p.reset_index(['Date', 'Ticker', 'Close'])
      pivoted = d.pivot_table(index = ['Date'], columns =['Ticker'])
      pivoted.columns = pivoted.columns.droplevel(0)
      return pivoted

closes = get_historical_closes(['LT' or 'HDFC'or 'ACC'], '1999-01-01', '2014-12-31')
```

My problem is I just want to get data for a few rows namely, data for LT, HDFC and ACC for all the dates, but when I execute the function, I am getting data for all the rows (approx. 1500 nos.)
How can I slice the dataframe, so that I get only selected rows and not the entire dataframe?

Raw input data is a collection of text files as so:

```
20MICRONS,20150401,36.5,38.95,35.8,37.35,64023,0
3IINFOTECH,20150401,5.9,6.3,5.8,6.2,1602365,0
3MINDIA,20150401,7905,7905,7850,7879.6,310,0
8KMILES,20150401,710.05,721,706,712.9,20196,0
A2ZINFRA,20150401,15.5,16.55,15.2,16,218219,0
AARTIDRUGS,20150401,648.95,665.5,639.65,648.25,42927,0
AARTIIND,20150401,348,349.4,340.3,341.85,122071,0
AARVEEDEN,20150401,42,42.9,41.55,42.3,627,0
ABAN,20150401,422,434.3,419,429.1,625857,0
ABB,20150401,1266.05,1284,1266,1277.45,70294,0
ABBOTINDIA,20150401,3979.25,4009.95,3955.3,3981.25,2677,0
ABCIL,20150401,217.8,222.95,217,221.65,11583,0
ABGSHIP,20150401,225,225,215.3,220.2,237737,0
ABIRLANUVO,20150401,1677,1677,1639.25,1666.7,106336,0
ACC,20150401,1563.7,1591.3,1553.2,1585.9,176063,0
ACCELYA,20150401,932,953.8,923,950.5,4297,0
ACE,20150401,40.1,41.7,40.05,41.15,356130,0
ACROPETAL,20150401,2.75,3,2.7,2.85,33380,0
ADANIENT,20150401,608.8,615.8,603,612.4,868006,0
ADANIPORTS,20150401,308.45,312.05,306.1,310.95,1026200,0
ADANIPOWER,20150401,46.7,48,46.7,47.75,3015649,0
ADFFOODS,20150401,60.5,60.5,58.65,59.75,23532,0
ADHUNIK,20150401,20.95,21.75,20.8,21.2,149431,0
ADORWELD,20150401,224.9,224.9,215.65,219.2,2743,0
ADSL,20150401,19,20,18.7,19.65,35053,0
ADVANIHOTR,20150401,43.1,43.1,43,43,100,0
ADVANTA,20150401,419.9,430.05,418,428,16206,0
AEGISCHEM,20150401,609,668,600,658.4,264828,0
AFL,20150401,65.25,70,65.25,68.65,9507,0
AGARIND,20150401,95,100,87.25,97.45,14387,0
AGCNET,20150401,91.95,93.75,91.4,93,2453,0
AGRITECH,20150401,5.5,6.1,5.5,5.75,540,0
AGRODUTCH,20150401,2.7,2.7,2.6,2.7,451,0
AHLEAST,20150401,196,202.4,185,192.25,357,0
AHLUCONT,20150401,249.5,258.3,246,251.3,44541,0
AHLWEST,20150401,123.9,129.85,123.9,128.35,688,0
AHMEDFORGE,20150401,229.5,237.35,228,231.45,332680,0
AIAENG,20150401,1268,1268,1204.95,1214.1,48950,0
AIL,20150401,735,747.9,725.1,734.8,31780,0
AJANTPHARM,20150401,1235,1252,1207.05,1223.3,126442,0
AJMERA,20150401,118.7,121.9,117.2,118.45,23005,0
AKSHOPTFBR,20150401,14.3,14.8,14.15,14.7,214028,0
AKZOINDIA,20150401,1403.95,1412,1392,1400.7,17115,0
ALBK,20150401,99.1,101.65,99.1,101.4,2129046,0
ALCHEM,20150401,27.9,32.5,27.15,31.6,32338,0
ALEMBICLTD,20150401,34.6,36.7,34.3,36.45,692688,0
ALICON,20150401,280,288,279.05,281.05,5937,0
ALKALI,20150401,31.6,34.2,31.6,33.95,4663,0
ALKYLAMINE,20150401,314,334,313.1,328.8,1515,0
ALLCARGO,20150401,317,323.5,315,319.15,31056,0
ALLSEC,20150401,21.65,22.5,21.6,21.6,435,0
ALMONDZ,20150401,10.6,10.95,10.5,10.75,23600,0
ALOKTEXT,20150401,7.5,8.2,7.4,7.95,8145264,0
ALPA,20150401,11.85,11.85,10.75,11.8,3600,0
ALPHAGEO,20150401,384.3,425.05,383.95,419.75,13308,0
ALPSINDUS,20150401,1.85,1.85,1.85,1.85,1050,0
ALSTOMT&D,20150401,585.85,595,576.65,588.4,49234,0
AMARAJABAT,20150401,836.5,847.75,831,843.9,121150,0
AMBIKCO,20150401,790,809,780.25,802.6,4879,0
AMBUJACEM,20150401,254.95,261.4,253.4,260.25,1346375,0
AMDIND,20150401,20.5,22.75,20.5,22.3,693,0
AMRUTANJAN,20150401,480,527.05,478.35,518.3,216407,0
AMTEKAUTO,20150401,144.5,148.45,144.2,147.45,552874,0
AMTEKINDIA,20150401,55.6,58.3,55.1,57.6,700465,0
AMTL,20150401,13.75,14.45,13.6,14.45,2111,0
ANANTRAJ,20150401,39.9,40.3,39.35,40.05,376564,0
ANDHRABANK,20150401,78.35,80.8,78.2,80.55,993038,0
ANDHRACEMT,20150401,8.85,9.3,8.75,9.1,15848,0
ANDHRSUGAR,20150401,92.05,98.95,91.55,96.15,11551,0
ANGIND,20150401,36.5,36.9,35.6,36.5,34758,0
ANIKINDS,20150401,22.95,24.05,22.95,24.05,1936,0
ANKITMETAL,20150401,2.85,3.25,2.85,3.15,29101,0
ANSALAPI,20150401,23.45,24,23.45,23.8,76723,0
ANSALHSG,20150401,29.9,29.9,28.75,29.65,7748,0
ANTGRAPHIC,20150401,0.1,0.15,0.1,0.15,23500,0
APARINDS,20150401,368.3,375.6,368.3,373.45,2719,0
APCOTEXIND,20150401,505,505,481.1,495.85,3906,0
APLAPOLLO,20150401,411.5,434,411.5,428.65,88113,0
APLLTD,20150401,458.9,464,450,454.7,72075,0
APOLLOHOSP,20150401,1351,1393.85,1351,1390,132827,0
APOLLOTYRE,20150401,169.65,175.9,169,175.2,3515274,0
APOLSINHOT,20150401,195,197,194.3,195.2,71,0
APTECHT,20150401,57.6,61,57,59.7,206475,0
ARCHIDPLY,20150401,32.95,35.8,32.5,35.35,103036,0
ARCHIES,20150401,19.05,19.4,18.8,19.25,46840,0
ARCOTECH,20150401,342.5,350,339.1,345.2,44142,0
ARIES,20150401,106.75,113.9,105,112.7,96825,0
ARIHANT,20150401,43.5,50,43.5,49.3,1647,0
AROGRANITE,20150401,61.5,62,59.55,60.15,2293,0
ARROWTEX,20150401,25.7,27.8,25.1,26.55,17431,0
ARSHIYA,20150401,39.55,41.5,39,40,69880,0
ARSSINFRA,20150401,34.65,36.5,34.6,36.3,71442,0
ARVIND,20150401,260.85,268.2,259,267.2,1169433,0
ARVINDREM,20150401,15.9,17.6,15.5,17.6,5407412,0
ASAHIINDIA,20150401,145,145,141,142.45,16240,0
ASAHISONG,20150401,113,116.7,112.15,115.85,5475,0
ASAL,20150401,45.8,45.8,38,43.95,7429,0
ASHAPURMIN,20150401,74,75.4,74,74.05,36406,0
ASHIANA,20150401,248,259,246.3,249.5,21284,0
ASHIMASYN,20150401,8.4,8.85,8.05,8.25,3253,0
ASHOKA,20150401,175.1,185.4,175.1,183.75,1319134,0
ASHOKLEY,20150401,72.7,74.75,72.7,74.05,17233199,0
ASIANHOTNR,20150401,104.45,107.8,101.1,105.15,780,0
ASIANPAINT,20150401,810,825.9,803.5,821.7,898480,0
ASIANTILES,20150401,116.25,124.4,116.25,123.05,31440,0
ASSAMCO,20150401,4.05,4.3,4.05,4.3,476091,0
ASTEC,20150401,148.5,154.5,146,149.2,322308,0
ASTRAL,20150401,447.3,451.3,435.15,448.6,64889,0
ASTRAMICRO,20150401,146.5,151.9,145.2,150.05,735681,0
ASTRAZEN,20150401,908,940.95,908,920.35,3291,0
ATFL,20150401,635,648,625.2,629.25,6202,0
ATLANTA,20150401,67.2,71,67.2,68.6,238683,0
ATLASCYCLE,20150401,203.9,210.4,203,208.05,25208,0
ATNINTER,20150401,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,1704,0
ATUL,20150401,1116,1160,1113,1153.05,32969,0
ATULAUTO,20150401,556.55,576.9,555.9,566.25,59117,0
AURIONPRO,20150401,192.3,224.95,191.8,217.55,115464,0
AUROPHARMA,20150401,1215,1252,1215,1247.4,1140111,0
AUSOMENT,20150401,22.6,22.6,21.7,21.7,2952,0
AUSTRAL,20150401,0.5,0.55,0.5,0.5,50407,0
AUTOAXLES,20150401,834.15,834.15,803,810.2,4054,0
AUTOIND,20150401,60,65,59.15,63.6,212036,0
AUTOLITIND,20150401,36,39,35.2,37.65,14334,0
AVTNPL,20150401,27,28,26.7,27.9,44803,0
AXISBANK,20150401,557.7,572,555.25,569.65,3753262,0
AXISCADES,20150401,335.4,345,331.4,339.65,524538,0
AXISGOLD,20150401,2473.95,2493,2461.1,2483.15,138,0
BAFNAPHARM,20150401,29.95,31.45,29.95,30.95,21136,0
BAGFILMS,20150401,3.05,3.1,2.9,3,31278,0
BAJAJ-AUTO,20150401,2027.05,2035,2002.95,2019.8,208545,0
BAJAJCORP,20150401,459,482,454,466.95,121972,0
BAJAJELEC,20150401,230,234.8,229,232.4,95432,0
BAJAJFINSV,20150401,1412,1447.5,1396,1427.55,44811,0
BAJAJHIND,20150401,14.5,14.8,14.2,14.6,671746,0
BAJAJHLDNG,20150401,1302.3,1329.85,1285.05,1299.9,24626,0
BAJFINANCE,20150401,4158,4158,4062.2,4140.05,12923,0
BALAJITELE,20150401,65.75,67.9,65.3,67.5,47063,0
BALAMINES,20150401,81.5,83.5,81.5,83.45,6674,0
BALKRISIND,20150401,649,661,640,655,16919,0
BALLARPUR,20150401,13.75,13.95,13.5,13.9,271962,0
BALMLAWRIE,20150401,568.05,580.9,562.2,576.75,17423,0
BALPHARMA,20150401,68.9,74.2,67.1,68.85,84178,0
BALRAMCHIN,20150401,50.95,50.95,49.3,50,84400,0
BANARBEADS,20150401,33,39.5,33,39.25,1077,0
BANARISUG,20150401,834.7,855,820,849.85,618,0
BANCOINDIA,20150401,105,107.5,103.25,106.8,11765,0
BANG,20150401,6.2,6.35,6.1,6.35,9639,0
BANKBARODA,20150401,162.75,170.4,162.05,168.9,2949846,0
BANKBEES,20150401,1813.45,1863,1807,1859.78,19071,0
BANKINDIA,20150401,194.6,209.8,194.05,205.75,3396490,0
BANSWRAS,20150401,65,65,60.1,63.9,6238,0
BARTRONICS,20150401,11.45,11.85,11.35,11.6,109658,0
BASF,20150401,1115,1142,1115,1124.65,14009,0
BASML,20150401,184,192,183.65,191.6,642,0
BATAINDIA,20150401,1095,1104.9,1085,1094.7,137166,0
BAYERCROP,20150401,3333,3408.3,3286.05,3304.55,8839,0
BBL,20150401,627.95,641.4,622.2,629.8,5261,0
BBTC,20150401,441,458,431.3,449.15,141334,0
BEDMUTHA,20150401,16.85,18,16.25,17.95,16412,0
BEL,20150401,3355,3595,3350,3494.2,582755,0
BEML,20150401,1100,1163.8,1086,1139.2,631231,0
BEPL,20150401,22.1,22.45,21.15,22.3,5459,0
BERGEPAINT,20150401,209.3,216.9,208.35,215.15,675963,0
BFINVEST,20150401,168.8,176.8,159.5,172.7,113352,0
BFUTILITIE,20150401,707.4,741,702.05,736.05,1048274,0
BGLOBAL,20150401,2.9,3.05,2.9,3.05,16500,0
BGRENERGY,20150401,117.35,124,117.35,122.3,207979,0
BHAGYNAGAR,20150401,17.9,17.9,16.95,17.5,1136,0
BHARATFORG,20150401,1265.05,1333.1,1265.05,1322.6,704419,0
BHARATGEAR,20150401,73.5,77.7,72.7,75.9,13730,0
BHARATRAS,20150401,810,840,800,821.4,981,0
BHARTIARTL,20150401,393.3,404.85,393.05,402.3,5494883,0
BHEL,20150401,235.8,236,229.6,230.7,3346075,0
BHUSANSTL,20150401,65.15,67.9,63.65,64,1108540,0
BIL,20150401,401.3,422,401.3,419.35,2335,0
BILENERGY,20150401,0.8,0.95,0.8,0.95,8520,0
BINANIIND,20150401,90.55,93.95,90.2,93.3,27564,0
BINDALAGRO,20150401,23.4,23.4,22.25,22.8,111558,0
BIOCON,20150401,472.5,478.85,462.7,466.05,1942983,0
BIRLACORPN,20150401,415,420,402.8,414.7,11345,0
BIRLACOT,20150401,0.05,0.1,0.05,0.1,439292,0
BIRLAERIC,20150401,52.3,54.45,52.15,53.7,9454,0
BIRLAMONEY,20150401,24.35,28.85,23.9,28.65,78710,0
BLBLIMITED,20150401,3.7,3.7,3.65,3.65,550,0
BLISSGVS,20150401,128,132.55,124.3,126.15,261958,0
BLKASHYAP,20150401,13.7,15.15,13.7,14.15,118455,0
BLUEDART,20150401,7297.35,7315,7200,7285.55,2036,0
BLUESTARCO,20150401,308.75,315,302,311.35,19046,0
BLUESTINFO,20150401,199,199.9,196.05,199.45,1268,0
BODALCHEM,20150401,34.5,34.8,33.05,34.65,65623,0
BOMDYEING,20150401,64,66.3,63.7,65.95,1168851,0
BOSCHLTD,20150401,25488,25708,25201,25570.7,16121,0
BPCL,20150401,810.95,818,796.5,804.2,1065969,0
BPL,20150401,30.55,32.5,30.55,31.75,116804,0
BRFL,20150401,146,147.9,142.45,144.3,7257,0
BRIGADE,20150401,143.8,145.15,140.25,144.05,36484,0
BRITANNIA,20150401,2155.5,2215.3,2141.35,2177.55,245908,0
BROADCAST,20150401,3.35,3.5,3.3,3.3,4298,0
BROOKS,20150401,38.4,39.5,38.4,39.3,19724,0
BSELINFRA,20150401,1.9,2.15,1.85,2.05,97575,0
BSL,20150401,29.55,31.9,27.75,31,9708,0
BSLGOLDETF,20150401,2535,2535,2501.5,2501.5,122,0
BSLIMITED,20150401,27.5,27.5,25.45,27.15,728818,0
BURNPUR,20150401,9.85,9.85,9.1,9.15,144864,0
BUTTERFLY,20150401,190.95,194,186.1,192.35,25447,0
BVCL,20150401,17.25,17.7,16.5,17.7,9993,0
CADILAHC,20150401,1755,1796.8,1737.05,1790.15,302149,0
CAIRN,20150401,213.85,215.6,211.5,213.35,841463,0
CAMLINFINE,20150401,89.5,91.4,87.5,91.1,32027,0
CANBK,20150401,366.5,383.8,365.15,381,1512605,0
CANDC,20150401,20.6,24.6,20.6,23.25,9100,0
CANFINHOME,20150401,611.1,649.95,611.1,644.7,72233,0
CANTABIL,20150401,47.6,50.5,47.6,50.25,5474,0
CAPF,20150401,398.85,427,398,421.75,224074,0
CAPLIPOINT,20150401,1020,1127.8,1020,1122.65,108731,0
CARBORUNIV,20150401,191.05,197,188.35,190,42681,0
CAREERP,20150401,151.9,156.6,149,153.25,26075,0
CARERATING,20150401,1487,1632.75,1464,1579.2,65340,0
CASTROLIND,20150401,476,476.25,465.1,467.3,185850,0
CCCL,20150401,4.2,4.7,4.2,4.65,47963,0
CCHHL,20150401,10.8,11,10.4,10.8,69325,0
CCL,20150401,178.35,185.9,176,184.3,244917,0
CEATLTD,20150401,805.25,830.8,785.75,826.7,501415,0
CEBBCO,20150401,18.3,20.25,18.1,19.85,40541,0
CELEBRITY,20150401,11.5,12.5,11.5,12.1,5169,0
CELESTIAL,20150401,59.9,61.8,59.5,60.05,128386,0
CENTENKA,20150401,152,159.9,148.2,157.1,16739,0
CENTEXT,20150401,1.5,1.5,1.2,1.25,19308,0
CENTRALBK,20150401,106,107.2,104.3,106.3,992782,0
CENTUM,20150401,756.85,805,756.8,801.9,26848,0
CENTURYPLY,20150401,234,245,234,243.45,367540,0
CENTURYTEX,20150401,633.6,682.4,631,675.35,3619413,0
CERA,20150401,2524.75,2524.75,2470,2495.3,6053,0
CEREBRAINT,20150401,15.6,16.2,14.65,14.8,348478,0
CESC,20150401,604.95,613.4,595.4,609.75,294334,0
CGCL,20150401,173,173,173,173,9,0
CHAMBLFERT,20150401,70.2,73.4,70.2,72.65,2475030,0
CHEMFALKAL,20150401,72.8,77,72,76.3,1334,0
CHENNPETRO,20150401,69,70.35,68.3,68.95,160576,0
CHESLINTEX,20150401,10.1,10.1,8.75,9.4,1668,0
CHOLAFIN,20150401,599.85,604,582.15,598.2,23125,0
CHROMATIC,20150401,3.4,4.05,3,3.3,63493,0
CIGNITITEC,20150401,433,444.95,432,440,32923,0
CIMMCO,20150401,92,94.05,91,94.05,19931,0
CINELINE,20150401,14.5,14.95,14.5,14.9,4654,0
CINEVISTA,20150401,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,10,0
CIPLA,20150401,714,716.5,703.85,709.6,1693796,0
CLASSIC,20150401,1.5,1.55,1.45,1.45,7770,0
CLNINDIA,20150401,824.7,837.9,819,828.8,6754,0
CLUTCHAUTO,20150401,13.75,13.75,13.6,13.6,1414,0
CMAHENDRA,20150401,9.35,9.5,8.9,9.15,1005172,0
CMC,20150401,1925.85,1925.85,1891,1907.25,153068,0
CNOVAPETRO,20150401,20,22.75,17.1,22.75,1656,0
COALINDIA,20150401,362.9,364.25,358,363,1428949,0
COLPAL,20150401,2003.4,2009.9,1990.05,2002.5,92909,0
COMPUSOFT,20150401,9.4,10.05,9,9.7,15083,0
CONCOR,20150401,1582.35,1627.3,1561,1582.85,182280,0
CONSOFINVT,20150401,36.55,40,36.5,40,439,0
CORDSCABLE,20150401,25.55,28,24.1,25.8,15651,0
COREEDUTEC,20150401,8,8.85,7.6,8.4,890455,0
COROMANDEL,20150401,268.5,271.35,266.15,268.35,42173,0
CORPBANK,20150401,52.5,55,52.05,54.1,1141752,0
COSMOFILMS,20150401,76.9,80,76.2,79.25,21020,0
COUNCODOS,20150401,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,2850,0
COX&KINGS,20150401,323,324.85,316.5,317.8,76998,0
CPSEETF,20150401,24.2,24.37,24.08,24.34,180315,0
CREATIVEYE,20150401,3.4,3.6,2.8,3.45,8545,0
CRISIL,20150401,2049,2052.45,2000,2030.7,3928,0
CROMPGREAV,20150401,164.85,167.4,163.2,166.1,2739478,0
CTE,20150401,18.55,18.55,16.85,17.05,8260,0
CUB,20150401,97.35,98.75,96.4,98.3,182702,0
CUMMINSIND,20150401,879,900.95,874.75,889.9,358652,0
CURATECH,20150401,10.8,11,9.75,10,755,0
CYBERTECH,20150401,28.5,33.45,28.1,33.4,103549,0
CYIENT,20150401,509.9,515,495.1,514.1,30415,0
DAAWAT,20150401,105,112.25,99.5,108.4,26689,0
DABUR,20150401,266.5,268.5,264.65,266.55,642177,0
DALMIABHA,20150401,428.15,439.9,422.5,432.65,9751,0
DALMIASUG,20150401,17.5,17.5,16.45,17.15,12660,0
DATAMATICS,20150401,66.5,75,66,72.15,119054,0
DBCORP,20150401,378,378,362.6,369.45,8799,0
DBREALTY,20150401,67,67.15,65.8,66.3,212297,0
DBSTOCKBRO,20150401,47.6,47.65,47.45,47.55,24170,0
DCBBANK,20150401,110.95,114.95,110.15,114.45,935858,0
DCM,20150401,84.5,88.75,84.1,87,34747,0
DCMSHRIRAM,20150401,107.95,114.3,107.95,112.8,29474,0
DCW,20150401,16.75,17.2,16.65,17.15,270502,0
DECCANCE,20150401,310.05,323.9,310.05,321.55,446,0
DECOLIGHT,20150401,1.45,1.45,1.4,1.4,1100,0
DEEPAKFERT,20150401,140,144,138.25,139.95,162156,0
DEEPAKNTR,20150401,68,70.65,66.4,69.95,8349,0
DEEPIND,20150401,46.6,54.4,46.3,51.9,52130,0
DELTACORP,20150401,79.95,82.75,79.75,82.35,889247,0
DELTAMAGNT,20150401,36.6,37.45,36.6,37.45,60,0
DEN,20150401,121.45,127,121.2,122.4,59512,0
DENABANK,20150401,50.8,51.5,50.1,51.35,376680,0
DENORA,20150401,136.7,136.7,131.05,133.6,743,0
DHAMPURSUG,20150401,36.8,36.95,34.85,36.35,38083,0
DHANBANK,20150401,30.8,32.1,30.5,31.75,195779,0
DHANUKA,20150401,690,690,652,660.15,24958,0
DHARSUGAR,20150401,14.15,14.7,13.8,14.45,1748,0
DHFL,20150401,468.9,474.9,461.6,467.85,448551,0
DHUNINV,20150401,97.15,103,94.5,99.85,15275,0
DIAPOWER,20150401,44.9,45.95,43.3,45.55,126085,0
DICIND,20150401,343,347,341,341.95,7745,0
DIGJAM,20150401,8,8.15,7.75,8.05,96467,0
DISHMAN,20150401,168,172.65,164.7,171.8,778414,0
DISHTV,20150401,82.2,84.85,81.35,84.15,5845850,0
DIVISLAB,20150401,1770.1,1809,1770.1,1802.35,68003,0
DLF,20150401,157,160.9,156.2,159.7,3098216,0
DLINKINDIA,20150401,165.05,168,162.2,164.75,22444,0
DOLPHINOFF,20150401,120.8,134.4,119.5,130.2,190716,0
DONEAR,20150401,15,15.95,14.5,15.35,679,0
DPL,20150401,46.6,49,44,45.45,25444,0
DPSCLTD,20150401,17.15,17.15,16.55,16.85,916,0
DQE,20150401,24.3,24.8,22.75,23.1,57807,0
DRDATSONS,20150401,5.8,6.1,5.7,6,2191357,0
DREDGECORP,20150401,374.9,403,372.65,393.4,106853,0
DRREDDY,20150401,3541,3566.8,3501.7,3533.65,282785,0
DSKULKARNI,20150401,77.6,77.6,74,77.1,3012,0
DSSL,20150401,9.5,9.5,9.5,9.5,50,0
DTIL,20150401,206.95,231.75,205.95,219.05,1437,0
DUNCANSLTD,20150401,15.55,16.3,15.3,15.85,740,0
DWARKESH,20150401,21,21,19.85,20.7,9410,0
DYNAMATECH,20150401,3868,4233,3857.1,3920.55,59412,0
DYNATECH,20150401,2.85,3,2.85,3,3002,0
EASTSILK,20150401,1.55,1.85,1.55,1.75,9437,0
EASUNREYRL,20150401,40.05,43,40.05,42.55,21925,0
ECEIND,20150401,136,148,127,133.85,43034,0
ECLERX,20150401,1603.8,1697,1595,1600.65,123468,0
EDELWEISS,20150401,63.65,67.5,63,66.6,451255,0
EDL,20150401,23.9,25,23.9,24.4,7799,0
EDUCOMP,20150401,12.45,13.55,12.35,13.55,499009,0
EICHERMOT,20150401,15929,16196.95,15830.05,16019.5,45879,0
EIDPARRY,20150401,174.05,175.8,168.65,171.2,56813,0
EIHAHOTELS,20150401,228,232.8,225,228,85,0
EIHOTEL,20150401,107.25,110,107.25,109.5,57306,0
EIMCOELECO,20150401,399,409.5,399,409.5,184,0
EKC,20150401,9.35,11.15,9.35,11.05,350782,0
ELAND,20150401,14.3,16.45,14.3,16.25,191406,0
ELDERPHARM,20150401,90.5,91.5,89.45,91.5,23450,0
ELECON,20150401,66.5,76.2,66.25,74.45,6045416,0
ELECTCAST,20150401,19.8,20.55,18.9,19.4,1956889,0
ELECTHERM,20150401,25.9,25.9,22.2,24,14611,0
ELGIEQUIP,20150401,147.5,150.4,146.4,150,9475,0
....
ZENITH, 20150401,...
```

Comment: You want to filter the df first, if you pass a list of the tickers so `['LT', 'HDFC', 'ACC']` instead then you can do `d[(d['Ticker'].isin(ticker)) & (d['Date'] > start_date) & (d['Date'] < end_date)]` and then call pivot

Comment: tried it already. Doesnt work @EdChum

Comment: You'll have to post raw input data and more code to demonstrate your problem as I don't know if the issue your data and/or your code

Comment: Now I am getting the message : KeyError: 'Level Ticker not found'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `EdChum` code from his comment and add some clarification. I think the main problem is `d` is output dataframe `d` cannot be looped in cycle for, if you need one output from all *.txt files.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

def get_historical_closes(ticker, start_date, end_date):

    dfs = []
    #create empty df for output
    d = pd.DataFrame()
    #glob can use path with *.txt - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3215392/2901002
    for files in glob.glob('/home/manish/Desktop/Equity/subset/*.txt'):
        #added index_col for multiindex df
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(files, index_col=['Date', 'Ticker', 'Close'], names = ['Ticker', 'Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Null'], parse_dates = [1]))
        p = pd.concat(dfs)

    #d is output from all .txt files, so cannot be looped in cycle for
    d = p.reset_index(['Date', 'Ticker', 'Close'])
    d = d[(d['Ticker'].isin(ticker)) & (d['Date'] > start_date) & (d['Date'] < end_date)] 
    pivoted = d.pivot_table(index = ['Date'], columns =['Ticker'])
    pivoted.columns = pivoted.columns.droplevel(0)

    return pivoted

#function isin need list of columns, so 'or' can be replaced by ','
#arguments are changed for testing: 'HDFC' to 'AGCNET' and end_date '2014-12-31' to '2015-12-31'
closes = get_historical_closes(['LT','AGCNET','ACC'], '1999-01-01', '2015-12-31')
print closes
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error: TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp
in d = d[(d['Ticker'].isin(ticker)) &(d['Date'] > start_date & ...